# How to call the function m inside of this function defined as variable A?

Tags: javascript

Let's say, I want to produce an output of "Hello World" (that is passing this.name as "World"). How do I access the inner **m** function

```
var A=(function(){
    function Person(name){
    this.name=name;
    console.log(name)
    }

    var m=function(){
    return "Hello " + this.name;
    };

    Person.prototype.getGreeting=m;

    return Person;
    })();
```

Comment: You will have to create an instance of `Person` aka `A` as `const a = new A()` and then do `a.getGreeting()`

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a module pattern where you have a constructor `Person` which is returned.

---

```
(function(){})()
```

is called an IIFE. Its used to create abstractions. So for example, `m` is accessible inside that block but not outside.

---

```
Person.prototype.getGreeting=m
```

is exporting function that as a part of class. In traditional sense, its like method on abstract class. Any method part of prototype is accessible to all instances

---

```js
var A = (function() {
  function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log(name)
  }

  var m = function() {
    return "Hello " + this.name;
  };

  Person.prototype.getGreeting = m;

  return Person;
})();

const person = new A('Foo');
console.log(person.getGreeting())
```

---

#### References:

- [What are IIFEs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-iife/)
- [Prototypes in JS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prototype-in-javascript/)